# How to implement singleton pattern in notifier project c#?

Tags: c#, singleton

First of all, I will say about my requirement. I created my project with notifier in tray. After execution it created many instances in tray and gradually decreases to one. So I decided to use singleton to ensure that only a single instance is created.

I found the following code showing how to create a Singleton but I don't know how to implement it in my project and get only one instance for notification tray?

```
public class Singleton
{
    private Singleton()
    {
        // Prevent outside instantiation
    }

    private static readonly Singleton _singleton = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton GetSingleton()
    {
        return _singleton;
    }
}
```

Comment: The singleton pattern you've shown is effectively within an AppDomain. You're talking about a single instance of an application within a user session - that's quite different. (C# itself doesn't have any concept of interactions between processes; there's library support, of course.)

Comment: could u tell detaily about that library support .. @JonSkeet

Comment: See Mutex as per M. Nasser Javaid's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in entry point as

```
static readonly Mutex singleton = new Mutex(true, "AppName");
    static void Main()
            {
                if (!singleton.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("Another instance is running.");
                   return;
                }
            }
```